# Why is the movie called "Midsommar" instead of "Midsummer"?

Tags: title, midsommar

Why is the movie called "Midsommar" instead of "Midsummer"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The movie takes place in Hälsingland, a province in central Sweden. 
Sommar is Swedish for summer (Just as Midsommar is Swedish for Midsummer).